# EXCEL VBA, inserting blank row and shifting cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble entering an entire blank row. I'm trying to shift Columns A-AD (four columns past Z).

Currently cells A-O has content. Cells O-AD are blank. But I'm running a macro to put data to the right of the current data (column O).

I can insert a row using

```
dfind1.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
```

but it only seems to shift down from A-O. I've manage to shift down O-AD using a for loop

```
dfind1 as Range
For d = 1 To 15
    dfind1.Offset(2, (d + 14)).Insert shift:=xlDown
Next d
```

Is there a way to shift down 30 cells VS 15? Similarly, I want to shift 15 to the cells to the right. Currently I have another for loop setup for that.

As for the rest of the code, its below. Basically merging two excel sheets bases on finding a match in column A. I've marked the problem area. The rest of the code works for the most part.

```
Sub combiner()

    Dim c As Range, d As Long, cfind As Range, x, y, zed, dest As Range, cfind1 As Range, dfind As Range, _
    dfind1 As Range, crow, x_temp, y_temp

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("sheet3").Cells.Clear
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
    .UsedRange.Copy Worksheets("sheet3").Range("a1")
    End With

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
    For Each c In Range(.Range("a3"), .Range("a3").End(xlDown))
    x = c.Value
    y = c.Next

    Set cfind = .Cells.Find(what:=y, lookat:=xlWhole)
    .Range(cfind.Offset(0, -1), cfind.End(xlToRight)).Copy

        With Worksheets("sheet3")
            Set dfind1 = .Cells.Find(what:=x, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If dfind1 Is Nothing Then GoTo copyrev

            '**************************************************************
            '**************************************************************
            'This is the problem Area
            'I'm basically having trouble inserting a blank row
            dfind1.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown



            For d = 1 To 15
                dfind1.Offset(1).Insert shift:=xlToRight
            Next d

            For d = 1 To 15
                dfind1.Offset(2, (d + 14)).Insert shift:=xlDown
            Next d
            '**************************************************************
            '**************************************************************


        End With 'sheet3
        GoTo nextstep

    copyrev:
        With Worksheets("sheet3")
            x_temp = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            y_temp = .Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
            If y_temp > x_temp Then GoTo lr_ed
            lMaxRows = x_temp
            GoTo lrcont
    lr_ed:
            lMaxRows = y_temp
    lrcont:
            .Range(("P" & lMaxRows + 1)).PasteSpecial
            Worksheets("sheet2").Range(cfind.Offset(0, -1), cfind.Offset(0, 0)).Copy
            .Range(("A" & lMaxRows + 1)).PasteSpecial
        End With 'sheet3


    nextstep:
    Next


    lngLast = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A2" & lngLast), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range("B3:Z" & lngLast)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    End With  'sheet2
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: If this question were much, much shorter, it could conceivably be of use to other users. As it stands, I don't think it is.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to just shift everything down you can use:

```
Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
```

Similarly to shift everything over:

```
Columns(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftRight
```

Comment: Awesome, the shift down works for me, the shift right doesnt.
`zdfind1.Offset(1).Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlDown`
this is working find, the shift right is as follows
`dfind1.Offset(0, 0).Columns(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftRight`

Comment: I would remove your dfind1.offset(0,0). If you want a whole column inserted. Just use the Columns(1).Insert part

Comment: note that you can insert multiple rows/columns in one go without looping by entering the range in the `Rows` or `Columns` - e.g. `Columns("B:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight`

Comment: ok, so i re-tested this, and it sums into the same problem. It only inserts a row from A-O

Comment: OK, so I'm rereading your problem. You said there is only content in rows A-O, so how can you tell that it's not shifting down O-AD? Is it that when you copy your data into those cells it's not also shifted down?

Comment: so lets say, row 1 & 2 has content from A-O, but row 13 has content from A-AD. If I insert a row at between 1 & 2, it seems to only shift down A-O, leaving P-AD unshifted.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot though, with your help, I've managed to come to the expected result.... SO IM DONE WITH THIS!

doesnt matter how I get there. As long as I get there! Efficiency doesnt matter in this case.

Comment: Hmm, are you using just 'Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown' or are you appending it to your 'dfind1'? I replicated the scenario you've described in excel and it worked just fine

Comment: I was attaching it to the dfind1.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Addrisk()

Dim rActive As Range
Dim Count_Id_Column as long

Set rActive = ActiveCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

with thisworkbook.sheets(1) 'change to "sheetname" or sheetindex
    for i = 1 to .range("A1045783").end(xlup).row
        if 'something'  = 'something' then
            .range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy 'add thisworkbook.sheets(index_of_sheet) if you copy from another sheet
            .range("A" & i).entirerow.insert shift:= xldown 'insert and shift down, can also use xlup
            .range("A" & i + 1).EntireRow.paste 'paste is all, all other defs are less.
            'change I to move on to next row (will get + 1 end of iteration)
            i = i + 1
        end if

            On Error Resume Next
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
            On Error GoTo 0

        End With
    next i
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 're-enable screen updates

End Sub
```