# Excel Loop through worksheet to create new rows for parent item

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help in creating a simple VBA to create a parent row for a list of items with variables.

#### my screenshot

[image: Refer to my screenshot here]

As seen in the screenshot, right now my data is similar to the "before" table. I am trying to create a VBA script which loops through all the rows and creates new row based on the group. I want to create a new row for every group number, and on that new row, it copies certain values from the cell below it.

Thanks!
Nelson

Comment: You could make a piece of code which iterates through your worksheet, looks for text in column "J". When found, inserts a row above and moves the text there as well. You can use this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574969/looping-through-all-rows-in-a-table-column-excel-vba and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816883/excel-vba-inserting-blank-row-and-shifting-cells

Comment: First you need to make sorting for column named SKU then in vba code, make while loop if the e3 = 24 then "do nothing" else insert new row and add p to the sku code.  hopefully its clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Add_Row()

Range("I3").Select 'This assumes the first row of data after column headers is row 3

While ActiveCell <> ""

If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then

Selection.EntireRow.Insert

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).ClearContents
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Value & "P"

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Else

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End If

Wend

Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert blank rows like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 3    

    Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
      If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
        Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        i = i + 1
      End If
      i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Hopefully changing the cells should not be an issue now

Answer (score 0):

the following code should let you change it easily to your current and, possibly, future needs

I assumed, as per your linked example, that "Description" column always has one non blank cell at the beginning of every "Group" or "SKU" rows block

```
Sub CreateRowForParentItem()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim descriptionCol As Long, SKUCol As Long, productCol As Long

'------------------------------
' setting stuff - begin
descriptionCol = 10 '<== adapt it to your actual "Description" column number
SKUCol = 5          '<== adapt it to your actual "SKU" column number
productCol = 6      '<== adapt it to your actual "Product Title" column number

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetFruit") '<== change 'data' sheet as per your needs
' setting stuff - end
'------------------------------


'------------------------------
' core code - begin
With sht
    Set cell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, descriptionCol).End(xlUp) '<== find last non blank cell in "Description" column
    Do While cell.value <> "Description" '<== proceed only if it's not the header cell
        cell.EntireRow.Insert
        Call CopyAndClearRange(.Cells(cell.row, SKUCol))
        Call CopyAndClearRange(.Cells(cell.row, productCol))
        Call CopyAndClearRange(.Cells(cell.row, descriptionCol), True)

        Set cell = .Cells(cell.row - 1, descriptionCol).End(xlUp) '<== find next non blank cell up
    Loop
End With
' core code - end
'------------------------------

End Sub


Sub CopyAndClearRange(rng As Range, Optional okClear As Variant)

If IsMissing(okClear) Then okClear = False
With rng
    .Copy .Offset(-1)
    If okClear Then .Clear
End With

End Sub
```