# Setting cell that contains specific text as the first cell, or "x"

Tags: excel, vba

Have the below scenario;

- Worksheet with a cell (A30) that contains text "Important Notes/Terms".
- Macro that adds text to the row A31 (i.e. after "Important Notes/Terms") depending on a product code (with it's own notes/terms).
- When I add a product as a new row, the cells shifts downwards which means "Important Notes/Terms" is no longer A30.

How do I set "Important Notes/Terms" as the first cell? E.g. if I set this first cell as "x", I want to be able to have on the macro something along the lines of

`Cells(x + 1, 1).Value = "Notes/disclaimer for Product 2"`

Where x is the cell that contains "Important Notes/Terms". There will only ever be one x on the sheet.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you start any product insertions at A32, thus reserving A31 to your notes? - Further links: [Inserting blank row and shifting cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816883/excel-vba-inserting-blank-row-and-shifting-cells/15818414#15818414) and [MS Help Range.Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert) @lyaof

Answer (score 0):

Just define your target cell with a **Name** like this

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyXField", RefersTo:="=Sheet1!A30"
```

Now reference the location of that cell with a named reference

```
range("MyXField").offset(1,0).value = "Notes..."
```

now when lines or columns are added or deleted this named field will reference the desired location.  Just don't delete the cell, the **Name** is lost then.